# How to reference the --s3-bucket value in my Outputs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I do a SAM deployment from my local console. With `sam package ... --s3-bucket xy` I specify the existing s3-bucket where deployment relevant objects are stored. I want that bucket to appear in the `Output` section in Cloudformation but I don't know how to reference it.
If I look under `Template` in the web console I see the path:

```
Resources:
  MyLambda:
    Properties:
      CodeUri: s3://xy/1b26f7841...
```

So I tried to add

```
Outputs:
  SourceBucket:
    Value: !GetAtt MyLambda.Properties.CodeUri
```

to my template.yaml, but the deployment fails with `Requested attribute Properties.CodeUri does not exist in schema for AWS::Lambda::Function`

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you **can't do this**. [AWS::Serverless::Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-resource-function-return-values) does not return such information. You would have to use [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to get it.

Alternatively, if you pass the bucket uri as **input parameter** to your template, you can output the parameter's value directly.